# Bbedit: Remove everything except this pattern

Tags: grep, bbedit

I have a very large html file that contains lots of strings like this:

```
<tr id="post-21156"
```

I want to delete everything EXCEPT these strings. Each of the remaining strings should be on a different line, though.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No idea what `bbedit` is but `grep` is a tool to do `g/re/p`, i.e. `Globally match a Regular Expression and Print` the result. If you want to **modify** text then you should use a tool designed to do that, e.g. `sed` or `awk`. [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. Showing just 1 string you want to match out of context isn't useful.

Comment: The output ideally would be exactly what you see... the rest of the content is irrelevant. It could be lorem ipsum but it's html.

Comment: The rest of the content definitely IS relevant. It's always far easier to match the text you want than to not match similar text you don't want. The regexp `.*` would match the text you want but I doubt if that's the right solution for you. We also don't know if the text you want appears just once per line or multiple times per line or anything else that we need to know about your input to suggest a solution.